# Cannot build Nuxtjs project in windows

Tags: windows, nuxt.js

I want to run a Nuxt project (Nuxt 2.15.8, Node 14.7.3) on Windows 11. Inside the project, there's a custom module listed as one of the buildModule dependencies in the nuxt.config.js file.

When I run the project using npm run dev, it creates a .projectName folder and then attempts to locate plugins placed inside this folder. However, it cannot find anything, leading to a failure. Interestingly, when I remove the buildModule dependency, the .projectName folder is not created, and the build process proceeds. Nevertheless, it eventually fails with an error related to the usage of the removed module. This suggests that the custom module may be the root cause of the issue.

Strangely, when I run the same project in the Linux subsystem for Windows, it does not encounter the same failure, even with the custom module. Do you have any insights into what might be causing this discrepancy, and how can I make it work correctly in the Windows environment?

[image]

Comment: Probably a path resolution, since it's using backslash (not sure how to solve it tho).